# How to format whole numbers with .00 at the end

Tags: c#, numeric

I want to achieve the following: Whatever number may be printed to the console, it has to have **2** digits after the decimal mark. When the result is a decimal number, the program rounds it off to 2 digits after the decimal mark, so this is fine. The problem is, however, that whole numbers don't get .00 attached to them, i.e. 100 gets printed as **100**, and not as **100.00** as I want it to. I've been struggling with this for quite a while so I any help will be highly appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TorrentPirate
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {     
           int megabytes = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());        
           int cinemaPricePerMovie = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());     
           int wifeSpendingHour = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
           TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(megabytes/2);
           double downloadTime = time.TotalHours;
           double downloadPrice = wifeSpendingHour * downloadTime;
           int NumberOfMoviesDownloaded = megabytes / 1500;
           double cinemaPrice = NumberOfMoviesDownloaded * cinemaPricePerMovie;

            if (cinemaPrice >= downloadPrice)
            {
                downloadPrice = Math.Round(downloadPrice, 2);
                Console.WriteLine("{0} -> {1}lv", "mall", Convert.ToDecimal(downloadPrice));
                    }
            else
            {
                cinemaPrice = Math.Round(cinemaPrice, 2);
                Console.WriteLine("{0} -> {1}lv", "cinema", Convert.ToDecimal(cinemaPrice));
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("{0} -> {1}lv", "mall", downloadPrice.ToString("#.##"));`

Comment: What is the minimum code to reproduce the issue? The code you posted seems more than necessary

Answer (score 2):

Why not just display it as a string?

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} -> {1}lv", "mall", downloadPrice.ToString("#.##"));
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Try typing in the values 30000, 5, 50.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.ToString("0.00")`:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} -> {1}lv", "mall", downloadPrice.ToString("0.00"));
```

Or, you can simply use the format specifier `N2`:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} -> {1:N2}lv", "mall", downloadPrice);
```

See [Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} -> {1}lv", "mall", downloadPrice.ToString("#.##"));
```